# Add text hh:mm to datetime by formula

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a text field with values 00:15 - 24:00. I want to add these to a date time so that it creates an 'end date'.

E.g. If I had a datetime of 24/03/13 12:00:00 and added 03:00 the end datetime would need to be 24/03/13 15:00:00.

Likewise if I had a datetime of 25/03/13 23:45:00 and added 05:00 the end datetime would need to be 26/03/13 04:45:00.

The closest I've gotten so far is: [Date]+TEXT([Duration],"hh:mm").

Answer (score 0):

There are functions to get the individual components of datetime fields such as HOUR().  You will have to get each component separately, apply the appropriate logic to add the duration and then group the resulting values together again as a datetime.

Adding a value to a date can be done though it is based on a day being 1.  So you could potentially calculate the duration as a proportion of a day and add that to the original date.